# Does wrapping a node.js sync function make it perform the same as its async equivalent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs

Simple example without error handling:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function read(filename, cb) {
  return cb(fs.readFileSync(filename));
}
```

Would this be the same, performance-wise with regards to the event loop, as:

```
fs.readFile(filename, cb);
```

The reason I ask is that some of the async functions in the crypto library still throw errors instead of passing them to the callback. I would like to just make a custom async function that does error handling the way I want it, but am worried about using the Sync versions of the native methods due to the bad reputation they have in the node community for bad performance. So, is it safe to go about this the way I proposed by just making a wrapper function?

Comment: Why do you think that's better?

Comment: ... It's still synchronous, just with an additional function call.

Comment: @SLaks I was hoping to do some custom error handling instead of relying on the way the native libraries do it. However, it doesn't look like this does what I had hoped, so I'll still need to rely on the native async methods anyway.

Comment: @SebastianSandqvist: You can wrap the native _async_ libraries and add your own error handling.

Comment: @SebastianSandqvist: No; you can simply pass a callback and check the error argument.  If you're wrapping an async method, you can pass a callback that checks the error, then calls your own callback.

Comment: @SebastianSandqvist: Huh? Async functions don't throw; they just call their  callbacks with an error.

Comment: @SebastianSandqvist: No; that's a synchronous exception, which can be caught with a normal `catch` block.

Comment: @SLaks gave it a shot, looks like you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The whole point of async is that the actual work, which is done by `readFileSync()`, happens *off the event loop*.

It is completely impossible to call a synchronous function and make it async.

Comment: What about enclosing the wrapper with `setImmediate` or `setTimeout`, still bad?

Comment: @renatoargh That would be simply delaying when the synchronous operation occurs.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot in any way make an asynchronous function suddenly behave synchronously in native node.js (e.g. without creating another process or using third party libraries that do some threading).  It just cannot be done.

This does not help you at all:

```
function read(filename, cb) {
  return cb(fs.readFileSync(filename));
}
```

It just implements a synchronous callback which doesn't really solve any problem.  The code is still all synchronous so you get none of the benefits of async I/O.  The important async I/O benefit you're after here is that you want the main JS event loop to not wait for the file I/O to happen.  You want the node.js event loop to be able to do other things while the file I/O is happening in native code.  As long as you use `fs.readyFileSync()`, this will never be the case, no matter what you put around it.

---

If you have some async crypto methods that are throwing exceptions synchronously rather than passing the error through to their callback, that is poorly designed code and I'd think twice about even using that code.

But, you can work around it by wrapping the crypto functions in your own try catch handlers that will call the callback if an error is thrown.

Let's suppose you have a crypto function like this:

```
function badCryptoFunc(arg1, arg2, callback)
```

You can wrap is like this:

```
function myCryptoFunc(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    try {
        badCryptoFunc(arg1, arg2, callback);
    } catch(e) {
        callback(e);
    }
}
```

If the functions throws asynchronously, then even this won't catch the exception and the code is just bad and can't be safely used as there is no way to catch an async exception in most circumstances before it's called by the system, not by your code.

Comment: `You cannot in any way make an asynchronous function suddenly behave synchronously in node.js` -- well, you sort of can with fibres which the meteor.js framework use a lot of. But I don't really like the style. As for the other way round, you can use webworkers to make a sync function async.

Comment: @slebetman - OK, sort of with third party libraries running different threads.  If you want to get technical, you can go fire up a different nodejs process and run anything you want there and that can be "async" to the original process, but none of that is what the OP is asking or trying to do.

Comment: webworkers is certainly a solution to what the OP is trying to do. In fact, that's what it was designed for. You can sort of emulate web workers by creative use of ChildProcess spawning a REPL but since there're already lots of good webworker implementations out there just grab one from npm. The nice thing about web workers as opposed to some of the older thread modules is that the knowledge is transferable to browsers.

Comment: @slebetman - I'd love for you to show an answer with webWorkers in node.js that makes the OP's code actually work.  And, if the goal is to not block the event loop, why not just use the async `readFile()` in the first place?  I'd be curious how you make a synchronous call that doesn't block the event loop since that seems to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @jfriend00 My use of `readFile()` here was just an arbitrary example. The real reason I wanted to do this was that I found node's `crypto` async pbkdf2 function throws in certain cases rather than passing the error to the first argument of the callback. I was thinking I could just make a wrapper for the sync method, but based on these answers that doesn't look like a good option.